# restrict Input QSpinBox

Tags: qt, qspinbox

I have a `QSpinBox` and I want it to only accept positive natural numbers. This works fine, until I enter a dot `.`

If I enter `234235.23456`and change the focus to some other spinbox, the value is changed to `23423523456`.

So I am looking for a way to ignore everything behind the `.`

Is this possible without subclassing `QSpinBox`?

Comment: use a comma? Qt respects localization settings (IIRC) so that may help

Comment: Probably no, but QDoubleSpinBox with setDecimals(0) might be your workaround. :p Otherwise, just reimplement [this](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qspinbox.html#textFromValue).

Comment: I first tried the QDoubleSpinBox with setDecimals(0) but it acts the same way

Comment: Does it work as expected if you enter a comma?

Comment: the Spinbox only takes digits from `0-9` and if `setDecimals(0)` it takes `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix for my porblem:

```
QDoubleSpinBox * box = new QDoubleSpinBox();

box->setDecimals(0);
box->setSingleStep(1.0);

box->findChild<QLineEdit*>()->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp(QString("^[1-9][0-9]*$"))));
```